# How To Install Djigzo on Ubuntu?

Tags: security, mail

Can any one provide step by step configuration to install Djigzo?

[Djigzo Website.](http://www.djigzo.com/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This section explains how to install Djigzo on Ubuntu and Debian. Install required packages

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postfix openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless tzdata-java ant ant-optional mktemp wget libsasl2-modules
```

**Note: during the installation of postfix you need to choose a configuration. Select No Configuration”.**

**Install Djigzo packages** A full installation of Djigzo requires you to install the Djigzo engine and the web administration manager. The debian packages can be downloaded from http://www.djigzo.com You need to download the following two files: djigzo_2.5.0-4_all.deb and djigzo-web_2.5.0-4_all.deb. Note that the current version can be different in your case.

**Install the .deb**

```
 sudo dpkg -i djigzo_1.3.2-1_all.deb

 sudo dpkg -i djigzo-web_1.3.2-1_all.deb
```

Configure Postfix For encrypting and decrypting incoming and outgoing email. This requires some changes to the postfix configuration. Djigzo comes with a modified postfix main and master conf which should be copied to the postfix config directory.

**Copy postfix configuration file.**

```
 sudo cp /etc/postfix/djigzo-main.cf /etc/postfix/main.cf
 sudo cp /etc/postfix/djigzo-master.cf /etc/postfix/master.cf
```

Update aliases Postfix uses /etc/alias as the alias file. Make sure that the alias file is available and up-to-date.

```
 sudo newaliases
```

**Restart postfix**

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

**Install Tomcat**

```
 sudo apt-get install tomcat7 -y

 sudo nano /etc/default/tomcat7
```

Edit and replace the following lines.

```
 JAVA_OPTS=”$JAVA_OPTS -Ddjigzo-web.home=/usr/share/djigzo-web”
```

Configure Tomcat memory usage In order to allow the import of very large certificate files (.p7b or .pfx files with more than 10′s of thousands certificates ) Djigzo requires that Tomcat is set to at least 256 MB of heap space.

```
 JAVA_OPTS=”$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx256M”
```

Disable Java security manager Djigzo currently does not function properly when the Tomcat Java security manager is enabled. The Tomcat Java security manager should therefore be disabled.

```
 TOMCAT7_SECURITY=no
```

Allow reading and writing of SSL certificate If you want to allow the upload of new SSL certificates using the Djigzo web admin SSL manager, Tomcat should be allowed to read and write the SSL certificate.

```
 sudo chown tomcat7:djigzo /usr/share/djigzo-web/ssl/sslCertificate.p12
```

Adding a HTTPS connector A HTTPS connector must be added to the Tomcat server conguration. If the Tomcat installation is only used for Djigzo, you are advised to replace the existing Tomcat configuration file (/etc/tomcat7/server.xml) with the configuration file provided by Djigzo.

```
 sudo cp /usr/share/djigzo-web/conf/tomcat/server.xml /etc/tomcat7
```

**Note: if you want to keep the existing server.xml you need to manually add the HTTPS Connector.**

**[A bug : add the following line in server.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240885/ssl-servlet-implementation-issue-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-p)**

```
 SSLEnabled=”true”
```

Adding a context A Djigzo context must now be added to Tomcat. djigzo.xml

```
 sudo nano /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/djigzo.xml
```

add the following text in it.

```
 <Context docBase=”/usr/share/djigzo-web/djigzo.war” unpackWAR=”false”/>

 sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart
```

Open the Web Admin page Djigzo should now be running (wait some time for Tomcat to start up). The login page can be accessed using the following URL https:// ip-address :8443/djigzo (change the IP address accordingly)

Note: Djigzo comes with a default SSL certificate which is not trusted by your browser. You should therefore manually accept the HTTPS certificate.

Login Use the following login credentials:

```
 username: admin
 password: admin
```

[image]

[vigilantsecure.com](http://vigilantsecure.com/2014/03/16/djigzo-on-ubuntu/) & [Djigzo Docs](ftp://ftp.pku.edu.cn/open/mail/Dijgzo/doc/quick-install-guide.pdf)